# Blacklist a directory with Zend Opcache

Tags: php, zend-framework, opcache

How can i tell Zend Opcache **not** to cache any files from a specific directory.
For e.g `/var/www/public_html/devzone/*`

I use `PHP 5.5.13` with `Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should set the [`opcache.blacklist_filename`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.blacklist-filename) configuration value with a file path to your blacklist.

> The location of the OPcache blacklist file. A blacklist file is a text file containing the names of files that should not be accelerated, one per line. Wildcards are allowed, and prefixes can also be provided. Lines starting with a semi-colon are ignored as comments.

---

For example, create a new file:

```
/etc/php5/opcache-blacklist.txt
```

Save with your wildcard setting:

```
/var/www/public_html/devzone/*
```

And add the blacklist file path to your `php.ini`:

```
opcache.blacklist_filename=/etc/php5/opcache-blacklist.txt
```

Comment: I found the cause for why it's not working on Windows. Look [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/6a010ad492ec82ce333fb4fee81fc46fc8e6a0a9/Zend/zend_virtual_cwd.c#L1263), this causes the opcache module to fail resolving paths from the blacklist file. To work around the problem, just don't use any wildcards in the path string.