# wp-admin being cached by Apache

Tags: wordpress, vps, opcache, ovh

My Wp-admin is being cached, I have noticed it because I have to reload every section in order to see it updated. I think it might be an Apache issue, something about the modules. I'm not gonna lie, It's my first time on an VPS and I enabled them all.
Is there any modules that could be caching my admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of research I think I have found the answer.
It seems that **OpCache was in fact caching my WP-Admin**, I just had to [blacklist the folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231469/blacklist-a-directory-with-zend-opcache) and seems to be working.